# Is there a way to require .NET 3.5 SP1 as a prerequisite for ClickOnce applications?

Tags: .net-3.5, clickonce, prerequisites

I have a ClickOnce application that won't run unless the client machine has .NET 3.5 SP1.  When Stop() gets called on the Storyboard I'm running it crashes.  After I installed SP1 on my client virtual machine everything works perfectly.

My problem is I'm deploying with ClickOnce, and I've made .NET 3.5 a prerequisite, but I don't know how to require SP1 as well.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've checked the prerequisites dialog and it's definitely not there.  I'm running VS 2008 on a Win 7 box (64 bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Properties / Publish / Prerequisites and click on ".NET Framework 3.5 SP1" (instead of ".NET Framework 3.5")
:-)

Comment: @Nestor wow I swear I didn't see that last night at 2 AM =P  That's what I get for being stubborn and trying to solve a problem while sleep deprived!

Comment: it also happened to me plenty of times bro!

Comment: Ok so I see this on one computer which is running Windows Server.  However, my main dev computer is running Win 7 and it does NOT have this option.  What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

For this reason (and others), I don't give my end users the final [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) install location. Instead, I send them to a page/site that runs various checks on their PCs before allowing them to install the application (.NET Framework level is one such check).

If you can require FullTrust for this application, you can retrieve REG_SZ at the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5` for "Version" and compare it against 3.5.30729.01 when your application starts up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Bootstrap Package for .NET 3.5 SP1 in the Windows SDK bootstrapper package folder. For VS2008 on Windows 7 (my setup), this is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

This folder initially only had the subfolder named DotNetFX35 on my computer, which is for the .NET FrameWork 3.5 RTM (not SP1). I needed DotNetFX35SP1, and found this under (...)\Windows\v7.0A. I think the v7.0A is installed with Visual Studio 2010, but I'm not sure on this. In any case, I've made the bootstrap files available at my blog site at this address:

http://posts.nilzorblog.com/stackoverflow/DotNetFX35SP1.zip

Just download and unzip this package in a folder named DotNetFX35SP1 under (...)\Packages, restart Visual Studio 2008 and you'll be good to go!